# R Shiny text input not updating with jquery date-range-picker

Tags: jquery, r, shiny

I'm trying to use this jquery plugin (https://longbill.github.io/jquery-date-range-picker/) in a shiny app. It works, almost.

The calendar date picker (bottom left of below image) correctly sends the text to the text input (top left). But the server object, `input$daterange12` does not register the change from the text input unless further changes are made (ie, add a space, press enter, etc.).

The app is running at http://joebrew.shinyapps.io/daterange.
The code is at [github.com/databrew/daterange](http://github.com/databrew/daterange).

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBEo5.png)

How can I get shiny server to detect the change from the daterangepicker and update the `input$daterange12` object without having to modify the text box manually?

Comment: Do you want it to be always displayed or are you closing?

Comment: @amrrs I want it to be always displayed. This aspect is already working. The problem is that the text which is displayed in the text input box does not automatically get passed to the R server's `input` list. 

In other words, I can make a change via the calendar. This change updates the text in the input text box. But the input$daterange12 object in the R server remains unchanged, unless I make further manual modifications to the text input box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I don't even know why you would ever get any input at all.

First, the `change` event on the input does only trigger when changes are made manually, hence you having to put in a space.

Looking at the [datepicker's documentation](http://longbill.github.io/jquery-date-range-picker/) under **Events**, you can see that a custom event `datepicker-change` is emitted when the two dates are set. You have to subscribe to that rather than regular `change`.

But then, you should't use the `daterange12container` at all. This is just the wrapper, which you specified should contain the elements. It has no value attribute. So you are actually sending NULLs over the wire. Here's why I'm confused that you did get something at least.

That doesn't matter, however, since the `datepicker-change` event already delivers the dates that were picked (look at documentation again).

So you can make your code work by editing the JavaScript tag, replacing it with:

```
$(function() {
  $('#daterange12').dateRangePicker({
    inline: true,
    container: '#daterange12container', 
    alwaysOpen: true
  });

  // JOE:

  $('#daterange12').on('datepicker-change', function(event, changeObject) {
    // changeObject has properties value, date1 and date2. 
    Shiny.onInputChange('daterange12', changeObject.value);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, @k-rohde! Great explanation and perfectly working code.

Comment: @k-rhode, if willing, please email me:  joe at databrew dot cc, so that I can thank you for your help.

Comment: Nice answer. I tried getting it work with .bind() and kind of worked.